# Problems with map changing size depending on which layer is checked.

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I am new to OpenLayers, and I have started building an application combining Google tiles and my own wms from  Geoserver. Code sample:

```
var hilirPerak = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("hilirPerak",    
       "http://>>localhost:8080/geoserver/hilirPerak/wms", 
         {  
            workspace: 'hilirPerak', layers: 'hilirPerak:lot', styles:'',
            format: 'image/png', tiled: true, transitionEffect: 'resize', 
            units: 'degrees'
         },
         {
            maxResolution: 1000,
            singleTile: false, 
            ratio:1,
            isBaseLayer:false,
            tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom,
            buffer: 0,
            visibility:true,
            maxExtent: OpenLayers.Bounds.fromString("3.873635,4.074956,101.14974"),
            //ratio: 1.9,
            //buffer: 0,
            //displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
            //isBaseLayer: true,
            yx : {'EPSG:4326' : true},
            displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
            transparent:true    
           }
  );
```

This works, and for a base map I am using Google tiles, but the problem is, when I click the check boxes to activate another layer, the base map changes size to that of the chosen layer.

Comment: I'm sorry, what does the based map follow the size layer mean?

Comment: thanks for your comment, its mean, for example, my layer sized 500 x 500 and my based map follow the size of the layer, when i unchecked layer field the based map full screen. when i check back layer, the layer appear than the based map follow the size of the layer, mean bound of the layer

Comment: What have you set the size of the div holding the map too in css?

Comment: this my html : <body>
  
        <div id="map">
  <input type="checkbox" name="track" id="track">
        <label for="track">Track my position</label>
    
   <div class="span4">
   <div id="map3" class="map"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
 
       <!-- <button id="locate">Locate me!</button> -->
         </div>
<script src="../learnOpenLayer/geolocation.js"></script> 
    </body>

Comment: What is the difference between map and map3? Does map have any width/height associated with it, either directly, or via css.

Comment: do you have any suggestion @john Barca

Comment: this is my css: html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 98%;
}
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}  /* CSS Document */

Comment: i already delete the map3, the result still same

Comment: True setting <div id=" map" style="width:500px;height:500px"> as a test.

Comment: the result still same @JohnBarça, based map still follow the layer tiled..

Comment: OK, at this point, I don't think I can help without seeing the full example of your problem in jsFiddle.

Comment: thanks i try using jsFiddle, at let you know, thank you for your quick response..

Comment: this is link for jsfidle, you can try check n uncheck layer and see the problem that i face, i really hope you can help me : http://jsfiddle.net/4nrcx/1/

Comment: this my jsfiddle: new one http://jsfiddle.net/4nrcx/5/

Comment: wan, OK, will look after work.

Comment: I believe the problem is that you are mixing projections -- you have some layers in lat/lon or 4326, which is expressed in degrees and others like the google and osm layers, which are in 3857, meters. You can mix these if one is a WMS and the other a vector feature, but not if they are both WMS as the two projections cannot match up.

Comment: thanks for your reply..what your suggestion for me to fix this problem?really need your help..

Comment: Request your HilirPerak WMS in 3857, the same as Google layers. Seeing as it is coming from your own Geoserver, this should be easy.

Comment: result still same @JohnBarça..